# Information on synchronisation process for events between Salesforce and Salesforce Classic app

Tags: mobile, salesforce-classic

We are keen to understand how the Synchronisation process occurs between Salesforce "On-line" and the Salesforce Classic App, in particular:

1. What user actions trigger the synchronisation.
2. What automated regular synching occurs (if any)
3. Is there a limitation regarding number of synchronisations that can occur.
4. What is the process for us to request changes to the synchronisation process. (Increase frequency of synchronisations etc.)

Comment: Have you already referenced any documentation/guides which you've found lacking or confusing ? The Implementation guide contains a page on this: https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_mobile_implementation.pdf